# No Persistence provider for EntityManager with a custom dataSource

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, persistence, derby, java-ee-7

I know that there are a lot of answers on this topic but none of them seems to be able to solve my issue. So basically in my Java EE application I am registering my own Initial Context with a System property called "java.naming.factory.initial" and as a value the name of my ContextFactory. This factory is calling my Context and in this context I am creating my own data source with the following code:

```
@Override
    public Object lookup(String name) throws NamingException {
        if ("java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB".equals(name)) {
            EmbeddedSimpleDataSource dataSource = new EmbeddedSimpleDataSource();
            dataSource.setUser("");
            dataSource.setPassword("");
            dataSource.setDatabaseName("memory:DomainDB;create=true");
            dataSource.setCreateDatabase("DomainDB");
            return dataSource;
        }

        throw new NamingException(name + " was not found");
    }
```

Now when I try to create the EntityManagerFactory with the correct name of the persistence-unit it throws the following exception **javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named web**
I have created a persistence.xml file in a META-INF folder and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="web"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>calculator.models.UserInput</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have placed it in src/main/java/META-INF/. I have also checked the .classpath file of the project and see that the folder is not excluded and t is even generated in the war file that Maven builds.
Stack trace of the exception:

```
ERROR o.a.c.i.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver - Error occurred during error handling, give up!
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named web
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at com.sap.core.connectivity.jco.session.ext.RequestTracker.invoke(RequestTracker.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at com.sap.cloud.runtime.impl.bridge.security.AbstractAuthenticator.invoke(AbstractAuthenticator.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invokeNextValve(TenantValidationValve.java:182)
    at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invoke(TenantValidationValve.java:97)
    at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.callNextValve(RequestTracingValve.java:113)
    at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:59)
    at com.sap.core.js.monitoring.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named web
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at calculator.resources.CalculatorResource.createEntityManagerFactory(CalculatorResource.java:72)
    at calculator.resources.CalculatorResource.calculate(CalculatorResource.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

I have tried many various locations of the persistence.xml but none seem to work out. Can you guys give me any suggestions on why this might be happening? Thank you in advance and tell me in the comments if you need nay more information.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the exception that is thrown, together with the full stack trace of any nested exceptions as well.

Comment: I added the stack trace